# Importing com.android.dx

Tags: java, android

```
import com.android.dx.Version;
import com.android.dx.dex.DexFormat;
import com.android.dx.dex.DexOptions;
import com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfOptions;
import com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator;
import com.android.dx.dex.code.PositionList;
import com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefItem;
import com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile;
```

These imports are not working. But I don't know why: I have the Android.jar (the one in `sdk/platforms/android-20`) in my eclipse build path. Why am I unable to import these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up android.jar and navigate to com.android. You will notice the package com.android.dx is omitted.

Edit: You should be able to add dx.jar as a dependency. It should be located in android-sdk/build-tools/[version]/lib/dx.jar

Comment: Ah, then where is one supposed to find such package?